# Python GUI Calculator backspace and clear

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I'm making a simple calculator using tkinter. I have managed to get everything to work except for my backsapce and clear buttons.The error message I get is: 'TypeError: backspace() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' for backspace and 'TypeError: clear() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' for clear. I have looked around online tutorials but most of the tutorial I've found  don't seem to have this problem.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("275x300")
root.title("Calculator")

def calculatorTitle():
    labelTitle=Label(root, text="Calculator", bg = "black", fg = "white")
    labelTitle.config(font = ("Verdana", 12, "bold"))
    labelTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=55, pady=5)

e=Entry(root,width=20,font="Arial 12",justify='right', bg='yellow', fg = 'blue')
e.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=4, pady = 5)

def addEntry(ch):
    e.insert(20, ch)

def CalculateEntry(expression):
    expression = e.get()
    expression = eval(expression)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(20, expression)

def clear():
    e.delete(0, END)
    return

def backspace():
    current = e.get()
    lenght = len(current)-1
    e.delete(lenght, END)


def calculatorBoard():
    b1=Button(root,text='1',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(1))
    b2=Button(root,text='2',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(2))
    b3=Button(root,text='3',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(3))
    bAddition=Button(root,text='+',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry('+'))
    b4=Button(root,text='1',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(4))
    b5=Button(root,text='5',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(5))
    b6=Button(root,text='6',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(6))
    bSubtract=Button(root,text='-',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry('-'))
    b7=Button(root,text='7',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(7))
    b8=Button(root,text='8',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(8))
    b9=Button(root,text='9',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(9))
    bMultiply=Button(root,text='*',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry('*'))
    bClear=Button(root,text='CE',width=5,command=lambda:clear('CE'))
    b0=Button(root,text='0',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry(0))
    bBackspace=Button(root,text='<-',width=5,command=lambda:backspace('<-'))
    bDivide=Button(root,text='/',width=5,command=lambda:addEntry('/'))
    bEqual=Button(root,text='=',width=27,command=lambda:CalculateEntry('='))
    
    b1.grid(row=2,column=0,pady = 10 )
    b2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady = 10 )
    b3.grid(row=2,column=2,pady = 10 )
    bAddition.grid(row=2,column=3,pady = 10 )

    b4.grid(row=3,column=0,pady = 10 )
    b5.grid(row=3,column=1,pady = 10 )
    b6.grid(row=3,column=2,pady = 10 )
    bSubtract.grid(row=3,column=3,pady = 10 )

    b7.grid(row=4,column=0,pady = 10 )
    b8.grid(row=4,column=1,pady = 10 )
    b9.grid(row=4,column=2,pady = 10 )
    bMultiply.grid(row=4,column=3,pady = 10 )

    bClear.grid(row=5,column=0,pady = 10 )
    b0.grid(row=5,column=1,pady = 10 )
    bBackspace.grid(row=5,column=2,pady = 10 )
    bDivide.grid(row=5,column=3,pady = 10 )

    bEqual.grid(row= 6, column= 0, columnspan= 4, pady= 10)

calculatorTitle()
calculatorBoard()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: This part if an assignment where I have to follow some instructions.

Comment: Instead of `e.insert(20, ...)` you should use `e.insert("end", ...)`

Comment: `def clear():` and `def backspace()`: you define the functions with zero arguments. `clear('CE')` and `backspace('<-')`: You call the functions with one argument

Comment: Also if you change `command=lambda:clear("CE")` to `command=lambda:clear()` and `command=lambda:backspace("<-")` to `command=lambda:backspace()`, your code should work as intended.

Comment: @TheLizzard I know but my teacher alreadu have some instructions that I had to follow.

Comment: @AnisSiracha Ok then change `def clear()` to `def clear(command)` and `def backspace()` to `def backspace(button)`. Also in programming if you have an approach that works you should go for it. I dislike it when teacher try to tell me how I should code my program.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks that worked. I also like coding freely without instructions but what can I do, I need to get graded in this course

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Okay I understand the problem now, thanks for the help

Comment: @AnisSiracha Oh yea grades...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Do you mind writing an answer? Your explanation is very good and I want to upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def clear()` and `def backspace()`: you define the functions with zero arguments.

`clear('CE')` and `backspace('<-')`: You call the functions with one argument

To fix the problem, either redefine the functions to take an argument,

```
def clear(arg):
    # do whatever

def backspace(arg):
    # do whatever
```

or change the call to not pass any.

```
bClear=Button(root,text='CE',width=5,command=clear)
   
bBackspace=Button(root,text='<-',width=5,command=backspace)
```

Be sure not to do both -- you'll run into the opposite problem.

Comment: if not passing any arguments might as well just do `command=func` which will do the same thing as `command=lambda: func()` just a bit shorter